# Pre Selecting checkboxs in RadListView in Telerik

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radlistview

I'm trying to pre select certain checkboxes based off of what was selected in the tree.
I have currently in winForms

```
clBoxDivisions.SetItemChecked((int)Divisions.Chase, true);
```

I have converted this to a RadListView element and now I am trying to pre select certain items based off of what location was selected and hardcode that in my program in Telerik. I cannot however find out how to preselect the datalistview checkboxes. Can someone help me figure out the Telerik version of this line, I am also using c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to check an item in RadListView. If so, this can be achieved with the CheckedState property of a data item:

```
radListView1.Items[0].CheckState = ToggleState.On;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I have been trying to figure this thing out for a day now and I couldn't get it too.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Here is also a link to the RadListView documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/listview-checkboxes-and-editors.html